# cannot receive PBT_APMSUSPEND and PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC message on windows laptop

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to get laptop sleep notification and I tried WM_POWERBROADCAST. It works well on my PC  but when I put my application on the laptop it doesn't work.

```
LRESULT Cttt1tDlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case PBT_APMSUSPEND:
        {
            MessageBox(_T("sleep"));
        }
        break;
        case PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC: 
        {
            MessageBox(_T("resume"));
        }
        break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    default:
        break;
    }
    }
    return CDialogEx::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I also tried `PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification` on visual studio 2022 and it works. But `PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification` is not support on visual studio 2010. My application is build on visual studio 2010. So I cant use it.

Is there any way to get laptop sleep event on visual studio 2010?

Comment: You can start see on which header file is declared that ID in VS2022 and to try to declare it in your project, but that would be not simple do.

Comment: I'd give up Visual Studio 2010, which is really obsolete by now, and make your app work with VS2022

Comment: @Jabberwocky But my company use VS2010...

Comment: @ssroreo _But my company use VS2010_: OMG, I'm not sure if sticking with >10 years old developoement tools is a good idea.

Comment: @ssroreo anyway: you're looking for [`GetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress)

Comment: And your're looking for `PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification` in `Powrprof.dll`

Comment: You can find working code to resolve your issue at [github Ditto/PowerManager.cpp](https://github.com/sabrogden/Ditto/blob/195166bf932f409cad3c93b1ec78e0af66fbcf4b/PowerManager.cpp) , specifically the method `CPowerManager::Start` uses `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to call `PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification `

Comment: *"`PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification` is not support on visual studio 2010"* - That's incorrect. Whether an API is supported or not is determined by the platform running the code. You can compile code targeting Windows 8 in Visual Studio 2010. You just need to ingest a more recent SDK. Alternatively, you'll need to declare the missing function and construct an import library. You can use a text editor for that, as import libraries on Windows are just [ar archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)). You **do not** need to use run-time dynamic linking.